# Codeigniter Form Multiple Input Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to submit multiple input arrays in codeigniter, to be written to the db. I think I can handle how to do the db writing, its just getting all the data out of the arrays I am unsure of.

Here is a simplfied version of what I am submitting

```
<input name="datetime">
<input name="misc">

<input name="set[id1][order]">
<input name="set[id1][reps]">
<input name="set[id1][weight]">
<input type="hidden" value="{exercise id}" name="set[id1][ex_id]">

<input name="set[id2][order]">
<input name="set[id2][reps]">
<input name="set[id2][weight]">
<input type="hidden" value="{exercise id}" name="set[id2][ex_id]">
...
<input name="set[idn][order]">
<input name="set[idn][reps]">
<input name="set[idn][weight]">
<input type="hidden" value="{exercise id}" name="set[idn][ex_id]">

<input name="newSet[?][order]">
<input name="newSet[?][reps]">
<input name="newSet[?][weight]">
<input type="hidden" value="{exercise id}" name="newSet[?][ex_id]">

<input name="newSet[?][order]">
<input name="newSet[?][reps]">
<input name="newSet[?][weight]">
<input type="hidden" value="{exercise id}" name="newSet[?][ex_id]">
```

As you can see there are groups of `set` inputs, each identified by its own unique `idn` (which would ordinarily just be an id integar from db). So there could be any number of groups of `set[idn]`.

I also have the ability (via jQuery) to add further `newSet`s which are the same, but they just do not have a unique id set yet.

Its just figuring out how to work my way through the list of unknown quantity of `set[idn]` and unknown quantity of `newSet[?]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your problem how will you save the posted value?
Given that set[idn] and newSet[?] has already its own index id when posted?

Comment: @reignsly `set[idn]` is a known (extracted from db) index, but `newSet[?]` or probably I am thinking more likely `newSet[]` has no index set yet, as it is a new entry. I need to process through whatever is there, any number of `set[idn]` and any number (maybe none) of `newSet[]`. cheers

Comment: Then all you have to do is loop all the inputs using foreach and process each values inside the loop.